# Function returning FINISHED

Tags: python, scripting

Why do functions like `bpy.ops.object.add()` return `{'FINISHED'}` and not the object?

Wouldn't it be better to return the object if successful and `None` otherwise so that `obj = bpy.ops.object.add()` can be used (instead of `bpy.ops.object.add(); obj = bpy.context.object`)?

If the `{'FINISHED'}` is necessary, then wouldn't returning the object and finished value as tuple be better (`return (obj, finished)`)?

Comment: Not every operator creates an object and the way it's currently implemented allows code to handle the return value of all operators in the same way. Although it would be technically possible, it would also require a lot of changes to the existing code with only marginal benefits, like in your use case.

Comment: To add, this is the operator / context paradigm.  Operators adjust the context and return a status  So no, IMO  it wouldn't be better.  That said. There are a number of API methods that do return a reference to the created object eg create a new mesh `new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("New Mesh")` then assign it as the data part of a new object `new_object = bpy.data.objects.new("New Object", new_mesh)`   to create a new mesh type object with an empty mesh.